# Get latest log of Event with web3

Tags: web3js, events

I have read all the other answers, but it doesnt seem to really work for me.
At first I thought it worked but then I noticed it didnt.
What is the best way to retrieve the value of the last event that happened.
Sample code:

```
import { React, useState, useEffect } from "react";

const [counter, setCounter] = useState();

dex.getPastEvents('NewDeadline', {
    filter: {},
    fromBlock: 'latest',
    toBlock: 'latest'
}).then(function(events){
    for(var k in events){

        console.log(events[k].returnValues["_deadline"]);
    }
});
```

Of curse I could iterate throught them and get the last value of all the logs. But this doesnt seem like good practice.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple answer I just figured out myself:
Just do `fromBlock: 0` to get all Events, and as Index just type `events.length-1`. In the end really simple.

Answer (score 0):

With

```
fromBlock: 'latest',
toBlock: 'latest'
```

you can see only events from one last block. You need set fromBlock to 0 or latest-n to get more range